# Webview on iOS looks like zoomed in

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

Currently i'm working with simple RN application, which just show web page in WebView component. On android devices it works pretty good, but on iOS, it looks like page is zoomed in, iOS status bar and fonts are bold

Screenshot from iPhone 6s `React-Native` application
https://pp.userapi.com/c638623/v638623954/6c05e/go4v1P7SKyY.jpg

Screenshot from iPhone 6s `Safari`
https://pp.userapi.com/c638623/v638623954/6c055/FPDDWCY8YqI.jpg

On Android devices page looks like page in Safari

I use WebView attributres: 
`ref`, `source`, `javaScriptEnabledAndroid`, `onMessage`

And `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` on web page

Why page in iOS react-native application may looks zoomed in

**UPDATE:**
Need to set attr `scalesPageToFit = {false}`, and all will be OK.

**Closed.**